# Defenition of type parameter

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter

1. I dont understand a strong defenition of type parameter in generic class or method. It's a reference type such that... what? Does it just non reifiable type? Is it true that all reference type for compiler is reifiable or not reifiable?

2.Consider the well known code:

```
List<? extends String> strs= new ArrayList<String>();
? extends String str;//error
strs.add("sd");//error
```

Why `? extends String str;` does not valid? I thinked that if we declare a reference to a generic type, for example `List<E> strs;` for some type `E` then compiler define type parameter to a specific type `E`.

I dont understand what occur in the case `List<? extends String> strs`? Does `List<? extends String>` and , for example `List<String>` parsing similarly at compile time or `List<? extends String>` parsing different from `List<E>` for some reifiable type `E`?

Comment: You question is confused. It would benefit from a code example where you show us what you want to achieve and to code you tried to do that with.

Comment: [look to the Generics Tutorial oracle doc.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Comment: @Johan When we trying to add a some string to `strs` we have compile error. In the error descriptoin compiler cant find a method with signature `add(CAP#1,int)`. I dont understand completely how compiler does work.

Answer (score 1):

Generics are used to specify a type.

Consider the following class def:

```
public interface List<E> extends Collection<E>
```

This tells us there we have a List that can hold elements of any type.
Notice how there are no restrictions on `E`.

If we define a class like so:

```
public class MyList<T extends String> implements List<T>
```

We now have a MyList that implements List, but only accepts `String`s (or decedents).

Inside this class we can refer to `T`.

```
public class MyList<T extends String> implements List<T> {
  private ArrayList<T> internalStorage;
```

**Key point**
In the class definition we have defined what `T` is; it's any class based on String.
Inside the class T can thus be referenced.
However the flavor of T does not get fixed until the class actually gets instantiated:

```
MyList<MyStringType> test = new MyList<MyStringType>(parameters);  //java 6
MyList<MyStringType> test = new MyList<>(parameters);  //java 7, same but shorter.
```

Now Java knows what `T` means inside the `MyList` class T is a MyStringType.
Armed with is knowledge Java compiles the class and replaces all references to `T` with references to the actual class `MyStringType`.
It completely forgets about T.

Now inside the class note that everywhere `T` is mentioned it will get replaced by MyStringType.
But what if I want to handle a string, but not necessarily the MyStringType.

Solution:
I define a member like so:

```
List<? extends String> strs;  //Will fill the data in later
```

Now we have a List called strs that will only accept strings, but that will not be forced to use strings of type MyStringType.
This list is not bound to the definition of `T` that was fixed when `MyList` was instantiated.
When we assign a value to the `strs`, the flavor of the List if fixed. In your example it will be a List of String.

```
? extends String str;//error
```

The variable cannot be fixed, because its type cannot be nailed down when the class that holds it gets created.

Answer (score 0):

Generics is designed for read and not for write. This is why you can use generics in parameters for a method, but cannot use it for declare a variable that you can use after for read/write from it :-)

Comment: Actually, generics are suited for compile-time instead of runtime.